# Do I need a negative COVID 72 hours before departure starting from sample collection or result issuance?

Tags: usa, covid-19

It takes 24 hours at least to get the COVID results. If I take the PCR test on Monday at 8AM, and get a negative result on Tuesday at 8AM, can I board a flight that departs on Friday at 8AM?

From Tuesday 8AM to Friday 8AM, exactly 72 hours.

However from Monday 8AM to Friday 8AM, it’s 86 hours.

So when does the clock start? From the time they took my sample nose swab? Or from the time they gave me the negative result?

Comment: Where are you going (is USA your destination or departure point)? *Usually* it's from the time of collection since processing times vary. If the USA is your destination, the date is calculated using calendar days, not hours, after the collection.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever seen a destination requiring a pre-departure PCR test that didn’t have the date the swab sample is given as the cut-off

Comment: For Germany, the PCR test must be taken 72 hours before the **expected time of entry** (an unexpected flight delay has no effect). [2021-09-08: Corona Tests für Reisende | Wann genau muss man sich vor Abreise testen lassen?](https://www.zusammengegencorona.de/testen/tests-fuer-reisende)

Comment: Four days are *96* hours. not 86.

Comment: Note that your premises are a bit incorrect: a PCR test _can_ get your result in as little as 35 minutes (for example in the FRA airport, for 390€). Only the cheapo version takes ‘up to a day’, but even there usually less.

Answer (score 6):

For travel **TO** the US you can find the detailed rules here. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/before-you-go/covid-19_testing_required_US_Entry.html

The sample must be taken 3 calendar days (NOT 72 hours) before *departure*. Departure is in most (but not all) cases the first leg of your flight. Example: if you are flying from Munich to Frankfurt to New York (on a single ticket with normal layovers) the "departure day" is determined by the time your flight from Munich is scheduled to depart.

So if you first leg departs Friday, the earliest you can a test is any time on Tuesday. It doesn't matter what time on Tuesday you take the test or what time on Friday your flight departs. Flights departing at 23:55 are great, flights departing at 00:10 not so much.

Things get a little more complicated if you take your test in a different time zone than your departure airport.

For travel **FROM** the US, the rules of the destination country and potentially the transit countries apply. These vary all over the place, so there is no single answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the US, according to the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html):

- the relevant time is that of the test, not of the result
- the limit is 3 days calendar days before your flight, not 72 hours

So for a departure any time on Friday, you must take the test on Tuesday (at any time) or later.

Comment: That's correct if the OP is traveling to or through the US. That fact, however, is not addressed in the question. For other itineraries, the answer may be incorrect.